# Is it possible to set up my own DNS for my computer?

Tags: networking, dns, netcat

I don't know if I ask the right question but I hope this situation would give you the whole picture.

I have my PC which located at my apartment. As usual, I get access to Internet using service provided by my apartment.

The issue is I want to netcat from my Laptop when I'm away from my PC but I can do that since I have no access to router to forward the port for my netcat connection.

Is there anyway I can set up my own DNS like how teamviewer works?

P.S. I don't want to use teamviewer since it requires a little high speed internet so I prefer command line.

Comment: You should look up what a "reverse tunnel" is, it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

DNS is of no help here - what DNS does is translates domain names to IP addresses, but you have no connectivity at the IP level.

You have to fix IP level first (try [pagekite](https://pagekite.net/)).